# AutoCompleteTextView layout

Tags: android, adapter, autocompletetextview

I am creating my AutoCompleteTextView as follows.

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/mYEditText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:completionThreshold="1"
    android:hint="some-hint" >
</AutoCompleteTextView>
```

Then I am utilizing it via :

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, COUNTRIES);
myAcEditText.setAdaper(adapter);
```

However, I do not want the basic autocomplete to appear with just one word per row. For example I would like to show the name on first line and his address on the second.

Is there a way to implement custom adapters for AutoCompleteTextView ?

**** EDIT 1** : I tried implementhing the [Following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16962340/how-to-add-a-custom-adapter-to-an-autocompletetextview) solution.

Once I created the class, I am utilizing it in the following way. Which is not working.

```
    TwoLineDropdownAdapter adapter = new  TwoLineDropdownAdapter(myActivity.this, al);
    myET.setAdapter(adapter);
```